# Textarea with whitespace preserved

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, input, textarea, haml

```
new_form = f.input :contents, input_html: { class: 'contents-input' }
haml
%p= newsitem.contents
```

How to render `newsitem.contents` exactly way the author created with whitespaces?
e.g.

I love apple

Yes You are

awesome person.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `white-space: pre` which will preserver newlines and whitespaces, tabs, etc:

```
p {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

<sub>Of course, you want to make `p` selector more specific, so you don't target all paragraphs.</sub>

```css
p {white-space: pre; background: #EEE;}
```

```html
<p>
I love apple

Yes You are

awesome person.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the Rails built-in method `simple_format` which will take a string of text and render it using HTML tags to give it whitespace formatting.

Usage: `= simple_format(newsitem.content)`

Documentation:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format